# Can I use final nodes in activity diagrams to end a use case?

Tags: client-server, software-design, activity-diagram

I'm working on several activity diagrams wich describes different use cases about a client-server application. Can final nodes be used to specify the end of a use case and not of a process? For example at the end of the login use case both server and client don't end but they continue their execution for other interactions. Have I to use final nodes in this cases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help you:

http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_activitydiagram.html

> **Final Node**
>
> There are two types of final node: activity and flow final nodes.
>
> The activity final node is depicted as a circle with a dot inside.
>
> The flow final node is depicted as a circle with a cross inside.
>
> The difference between the two node types is that the **flow final node denotes the end of a single control flow**; the **activity final node denotes the end of all control flows** within the activity.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: This is my understanding from reading the UML spec (http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/); see fig. 12.91 on p385 and the related explanations therein:
Flow final indicates a use case is finished but the whole process might continue (in other flows); activity final indicates all flows of the process shown in the diagram terminate.